# Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "Delta"

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have redshift script

Here is the code of  part of a script

```
    SELECT  cog.organizationid,
        cog.clientid,
        t.MonthBilled,
        t.Month,
        t.Year,
        u.ClientCharges,
        cp.supervisorcontactid AS Principal,
        cc.fullname AS CSL,

        LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) AS PreviosMonthCharges,

        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE u.ClientCharges END -
                                CASE WHEN LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NULL THEN 0
                                ELSE LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month)
                                END AS Delta,

        CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE u.ClientCharges END - CASE WHEN LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NULL THEN 0
                                ELSE LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) END) > 0 THEN 'Gain'
             WHEN CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE u.ClientCharges END - CASE WHEN LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NULL THEN 0
                                ELSE LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) END < 0 THEN 'Loss'
                                ELSE NULL END AS GainsLosses,
        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges >=0 AND LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NULL AND t.MonthBilled <> '1/1/2015' THEN 'New' ELSE 'Existing' END AS ClientType,

        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 'InActive' ELSE 'Active' END AS ActiveStatus,

        CASE WHEN LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NOT NULL AND t.MonthBilled <> '1/1/2015' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS ActiveLastMonth,

        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL AND (LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) <> 0 AND LAG(u.ClientCharges,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NOT NULL) AND t.MonthBilled <> '1/1/2015' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS OneMonthChurn,

        u2.FeatureKeyCount,

        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NOT NULL AND u.ClientCharges > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OrgCounter
FROM    public.contacts_client_organization cog
```

I have this error message when trying to run it

> [42601][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "Delta" Position: 747; java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "Delta" Position: 747;

But I not understood, what's wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here is rewritten part with valid *LAG*, but I still have the same problem

```
 SELECT  cog.organizationid,
        cog.clientid,
        t.MonthBilled,
        t.Month,
        t.Year,
        u.ClientCharges,
        cp.supervisorcontactid AS Principal,
        cc.fullname AS CSL,

        LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) AS PreviosMonthCharges,

        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE u.ClientCharges END -
                                CASE WHEN LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NULL THEN 0
                                ELSE LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month)
                                END AS Delta,

        CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE u.ClientCharges END - CASE WHEN LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NULL THEN 0
                                ELSE LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) END) > 0 THEN 'Gain'
             WHEN CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE u.ClientCharges END - CASE WHEN LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NULL THEN 0
                                ELSE LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) END < 0 THEN 'Loss'
                                ELSE NULL END AS GainsLosses,
        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges >=0 AND LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NULL AND t.MonthBilled <> '1/1/2015' THEN 'New' ELSE 'Existing' END AS ClientType,

        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL THEN 'InActive' ELSE 'Active' END AS ActiveStatus,

        CASE WHEN LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NOT NULL AND t.MonthBilled <> '1/1/2015' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS ActiveLastMonth,

        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NULL AND (LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) <> 0 AND LAG(u.ClientCharges,1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid,t.Year,t.Month) IS NOT NULL) AND t.MonthBilled <> '1/1/2015' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS OneMonthChurn,

        u2.FeatureKeyCount,

        CASE WHEN u.ClientCharges IS NOT NULL AND u.ClientCharges > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OrgCounter
FROM    public.contacts_client_organization cog
```

Comment: This is a guess, but I'd try adding paretheses: `((CASE ... END) - (CASE ... END)) as Delta`. It shouldn't be the case. but maybe it's confused. Either  way, `COALESCE` is better when checking for `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but `lag()` doesn't accept a third argument for the default in Redshift.

I would write this as:

```
    (COALESCE(u.ClientCharges, 0) -
     COALESCE(LAG(u.ClientCharges, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid, t.Year, t.Month), 0)
    ) as my_Delta,
```

`DELTA` is an [Amazon Redshift reserved word](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_pg_keywords.html), so give it a different name.

Comment: What is COALESCE?

I delete 3 argument, and still have this error

Comment: It is the ANSI/ISO standard version of `NVL()`:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html.

Comment: I think you got error near `,0` at this row `COALESCE(CASE WHEN LAG(u.ClientCharges, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY cog.clientid ORDER BY cog.clientid, t.Year, t.Month), 0)`

Comment: @EugeneSukh . . . There should have been no `CASE` in the expression at all.

Comment: Yeah, but it still show me this error. Meh. I mean syntax error near "Delta"